# Writing thrown errors to a file in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, error-handling, throw

Is there a way to add a default behavior in javascript to the throw event.
Like I am trying to add to a file whenever an error is thrown :

Example :

```
 if (tables.length === 0) {
      throw new Error("NO_TABLES_RETRIEVED");
    }
```

I want to write to file first and then throw the error. I know I can add a function and just before throwing I can call that function but just to know more is there something like to add a default behavior with throw?

Comment: will you like to use try..catch block?

Comment: but in try catch also, I would need to call my function to write to a file. I am looking for that no matter where the throw is in the entire application in Node JS, wherever there is a throw my function should run.

Comment: You want it in nodejs right?

Comment: Yes in Node JS..!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error is different from Exception in Javascript w.r.t NodeJS. An error is any instance of the Error class. Errors may be constructed and then passed directly to another function or thrown. When you throw an error, it becomes an exception.2 Here's an example of using an error as an exception:

```
throw new Error('something bad happened');
```

but you can just as well create an Error without throwing it:

```
callback(new Error('something bad happened'));
```

Since you mentioned in the comment that you don't want to require the error handler file in all the files of the app. You can also make use of NodeJS [EventEmitter module](https://nodejs.org/api/events.html) or use a error handler middleware

Comment: I am gonna try this EventEmitter module. I was just thinking where to write the functions which are mentioned on the link. Say for example , I use emitter.on(eventName, listener), for this where should I write the code?

Comment: You can write it anywhere on your application (in app.js or in a separate file as you wish). Whenever you want to emit just emit `eventEmitter.emit('eventName');
`

Comment: Please, Don't forget to upvote or mark the answer a accepted. So it will be useful for others. @Akshy

Comment: yes, but I am trying the solutions right now actually. Again, I think I am getting a bit confused. The example you told me in the comment is emitting an event. there must be something to listen the event as well. So you are saying I should write some event.listen in app.js so that whenever an error is thrown my event listener will listen the Error event?

Comment: Yes `eventEmitter.addListener('connection', listennerFunction);` You can register listenner anywhere but before emitting the events

Comment: this will not require the change in throw new Error statement right?

Comment: You don't need to throw an error just pass the error in the params to the listenner to store it in the file. Read my answers first paragraph

Comment: I guess maybe you misunderstood the question. Actually I am having large number of files where throw error is there. I was wanting to add some default behavior to throw error because other than that would require lot of edits.

Answer (score 1):

I think your best bet is to use a custom throw. I actually always do it, to be able to write

```
_throw("MyErrorMessage")
```

So I would do something like that:

```js
//Should use something like dot-env with the path to your errors 
require('dotenv').config()

//I'm just gonna fake it to make it work on your machine:
process.env.error_file_path = './myErrors.txt'


//throwLib.js
const util = require('util')
const fs = require('fs')
const writeFile = util.promisify(fs.appendFile)

_throw = (stringError) => {
    writeFile(process.env.error_file_path, "Error : " + stringError + "\n").then(err => {
        if (err)
            console.log(err)
        throw new Error(stringError)
    }
    )
}
//import this in your files.
//myFile.js


//someStuff
_throw('someMessage1')
_throw('someMessage2')
_throw('someMessage3')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own custom error and do some logic in the constructor.

```js
function MyError(){
  //do some logic herer (e.g. write to file)
  console.log("some logic");
}

throw new MyError()
```

Comment: that would do, but it's just wherever I create this function I will require this file in each and every file of the application where errors are being thrown. Is there something I can play around with default throw new Error?

Comment: Just like Error is on the window object, you can put your Custom Error on window also.
Another option is to add some functionality to the default Error object and than call it before you throw it:
Error.prototype.someMethod = function(){console.log("test")};

Comment: yups but what I am looking for is to add a default behavior without wanting to go to each file and add a call to my function before every throw. This will require lot of editing.

Comment: If you are using node JS, you can throw a string: "some error".
Than on the root of your application add some code to catch it:
process.on('uncaughtException', function(err) {
  //check if the err is you error
});

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a NodeJS application, you can centrally manage all your thrown errors.

You should also name your errors:

```
class ApiError extends Error {

  constructor (message, code) {
  super(message);
  this.name = 'ApiError';
  this.code = code;
  }
}
```

Similarly use other names for other error types.

For an express application,

```
app.use(routes);

// place this after your routes in express app. This will catch all your thrown errors.
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    console.log(err);

    switch (err.name) {
      case 'ApiError':
        // write to file here
        return res.status(err.code || 500).send({error: err.message});

      case 'Some other error':
       // handle differently
       break;

      default:
       res.status(err.status || 500).render('500', {error: err});
   }
});
```

Note if you are throwing from within a Promise, async/await, this won't catch your error. You will have to catch them centrally some other way, possibly by catching all Unhandled Promise Rejections in your app

```
process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason) => {
  console.log(reason);
  // log error in file
});
```

Similarly, you should also catch all uncaught exceptions centrally

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
  console.log(err);
  // log error in file
});
```

*Suggestion:*
As far as logging errors in file are concerned, it is a great way to do that only if you're parsing your file by some other way, sending your file to logstash etc.

When you're not planning to parse your file programmatically, log your errors in an errordb / error-table. They are much easier to query that way :)